# How do i build a laser based tachometer?

Tags: laser, phototransistor, tachometer

I want to build a tachometer that has to be somewhere around 1 meter from the rotating shaft.

I'm still to build a prototybe based on IR diode and phototransistor, but I'm afraid, I would get too much noise from other rotating parts/vibration even if stated 100mA IR LED current would be enough to give me enough light.

So, i thought, maybe i could build a cheap red laser based solution, but the problem is - what photo transistor should i use to detect laser that is bounced back from reflective strip on rotating shaft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A laser could be useful for this since you can easily create a well placed small dot from the 1 m away.  Laser light is just that, light.  Any phototransistor or photodiode that is sensitive to the laser light wavelength will work.  You might need some optics to gather the reflected light from a larger area and then focus is onto the receiver.  That will greatly increase the signal to noise ratio, but will need to be aligned carefully.